# Why does facebook use an image sprite instead of base 64?

Tags: image, performance, base64

Facebook use a large image sprite for their icons:
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/_iosjUA7EMo.png

I thought that base 64 image encoding resulted in the best page loading times, is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not faster. Not necessarily. Base 64 encoding results in a larger file than binary. What you gain is the image being delivered in the initial request, albeit at a slower speed, for very small images where the image size is negligible this makes sense, but that doesn't mean it's faster across the board.

Comment: it may be faster if the server communication overhead exceeds the additional download time.

Comment: Happen sooner, but the actual data will never transfer faster.

Comment: the pure data transfer it self will not be faster. but if you count the http-request the server reaction time it will take longer  for small files and even may process more traffic.
Make a ping to a server and you will see, that this will require a couple of ms. on a 10Mb/s line you can transfer ~1kBytes in 10ms.

Comment: All explained above...not sure what point you're trying to make? Total download speed = latency + (filesize / bandwidth). This is assuming you've got spare bandwidth so that your client is just sitting there waiting for the request for the image to return. If you're using all of a client's bandwidth, base64 will be slower regardless. There are numerous highly detailed guides on how to optimize a site, this is not one and it is not a trivial task. The main point of this Q+A is just that base64 is not automatically the fastest way to send images to the client.

Answer (score 0):

loading many small files takes significantly longer than loading one bigger file of same size, because of the whole server communication overhead.

I don't think that embedding binarydata as base64 (6bit -> so overall size is a third bigger than pay load)  is so much better than requesting an additional image. maybe for very few small icons this may be true.

Another reason may be that exchanging themes is a bit more easy since only one image have to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is that IE8 has a max file size for base 64 images. As the facebook sprite is a very large one it may be over the limit.